# How and when should I run database migrations in this case?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, amazon-rds, database-migration, github-actions

I am maintaining an open-source Software as a Service project, which uses AWS RDS (PostgreSQL) as its database, and GitHub Actions as CI/CD pipeline. I am using Entity Framework Core as my ORM.

I've heard that it's a good idea not to run migrations during application startup - especially if you're on a scale-out system like mine with multiple application nodes.

That's fine, and I guess running it at the CI/CD step would be the best thing to do? However, I would rather not want my GitHub Actions to have access to the database (even if the connection string is described with secrets). Because right now, it is not publically available, and I would like it to stay that way.

In addition, I don't feel like my project is big enough to justify having a release management system like Octopus Deploy.

What do I do here? Is it possible to whitelist GitHub Actions only but not have public access in general, in terms of RDS? Am I even on the right track here?

I am also using AWS Systems Manager's Parameter Store (KMS encrypted), if that's of interest.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to whitelist GitHub Actions only but not have public access in general, in terms of RDS?

This should be possible, however range of IP shared by agents could be huge. You can get it vira REST api call as it is mentioned [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#ip-addresses). The list is updated each week so you should maintain your whitelist.

Another approach could be [self hosted agent](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) and then you are the owner of the agent used to build and deploy your code. You can the assign static IP and make whitelist maintenance an easy stuff.

Comment: Interesting. I feel like both are a lot of effort for my relatively small project, so that's bad news in my opinion. Is there any other way? Thanks either way.

Comment: As far as I know not. You cannot for instance assume that you will get a specific agent with given IP Address. This is random. In most cases it could be even the same ip, however this is not guaranteed. With self hosted agent you will be forced to maintain agent itself, so it is also a disadvantege. In this frist apporach you can create a scheduled job which will be updating your ip restriction daily based on the REST API given in docs. However, please keep in mind that actually anyone from github agents having credentials to you DB will be in power to access your DB.

Comment: You can also try to set ip restriction od DB at the beginning on job execution, than take it down at the end. Still some work to do.

Comment: Thank you. But if I set up IP restriction via GitHub Actions, and GitHub Actions has rights to that, then the IP restriction is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bastion host and then you need to ssh to that instance and then run the migrations there. I had done this before but not with .NET but with nodejs and sequelize.
If you don't wanna use a bastion use, then you can use AWS System Manager. If you need more info, check this [link](https://repost.aws/pt/questions/QU6EZxe_C8SHiVHbrwJoXiIQ/deploy-rds-migrations-from-github-with-actions) out.